# How can I stop ls from descending into directories, similar to prune for find?

Tags: directory, ls

If I type `ls *ro*` I also get files in subdirectories that match the `*ro*` pattern.
Is there any option for ls similar to prune?

Ideally a flag, otherwise perhaps an exec?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `-d` switch:

```
ls -d *ro*
```

.....

Comment: I wrote a script that gets the folder access bits (converted to 755 or 644 notation), date and time modified, and folder name, then sends the information via text message. I needed this to be <140 characters. This helped, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could use :

```
ls | grep ro
```

To accomplish the task.
Pipe the output of `ls` which outputs only the contents of the current directory to `grep` and to selectively output the files matching the regex pattern.

Comment: -1  How would the grep know if the pattern match was in the directory or a subdirectory?

Comment: Also it doesn't actually return anything.  Try it.

Comment: By default ls outputs only the contents of the current directory. So passing that output to grep returns only the data that matches the given regex. I tried the given command on my Arch system and it works perfectly.

Comment: Since grep takes a regex as input, do not add the asterisks around ro. As I have mentioned, just execute grep ro. This is a crude hack when compared to manatwork's answer, but works perfectly fine.

Comment: If you have an absurd number of files, though, the globbing in manatwork's answer may reach the limit of the command line length.  This won't.

Comment: I think I tried it with the *'s initially.  Without them I see it works.